# Translating from Python to C++

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, time, translate

I'm struggling to try and convert this from python into c++, please if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated. Assume that the timern and Day variables are already given so no need for the time.ctime(thing)

```
if Day!=4:
    timeschedule=["08:30","09:20","10:10","11:00","11:30","12:20","13:10","14:00","14:45"]
else:
    timeschedule=["08:30","09:20","09:50","10:40","11:30"]
timern=time.ctime()[11:16]

for i in timeschedule:
    if timern<i:
        Finishes=i
        Period=timeschedule.index(Finishes)+1
        break
    else:
        continue

timern=timedelta(hours=int(timern[0:2]), minutes=int(timern[3:5]))
Finishes=timedelta(hours=int(Finishes[0:2]), minutes=int(Finishes[3:5]))

TimeLeft= Finishes-timern

seconds = TimeLeft.total_seconds()
hours = seconds // 3600
minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
seconds = seconds % 60
DayL=Days[Day]
Output=str(minutes)[0:2]+" minutes left till "+DayL[Period]
```

Here is my attempt at the conversion:

```
if (getCurrentDOWAsString=="Saturday" || getCurrentDOWAsString=="Sunday") {
  break;
}
else if (getCurrentDOWAsString=="Friday") {
  static const char *TimeSchedule[5] = {"08:30","09:20","09:50","10:40","11:30"};
}
else {
  static const char *TimeSchedule[9] = {"08:30","09:20","10:10","11:00","11:30","12:20","13:10","14:00","14:45"};
}

int Cn=0;
for (std::list<TimeSchedule>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it){
    std::cout << it->name;
    int Cn=Cn+1;
    if (CTime < it) {
      char Finishes=it;
      int Period=Cn;
      break;    
}
int FinH = Finishes.substr(0,2);
int FinM = Finishes.substr(3,2);
if(FinM.minutes > minutes.minutes) {
  --hours.hours;
  minutes.inutes += 60;
}
  difference->minutes = minutes.minutes-FinM.minutes;
  difference->hours = hours.hours-FinH.hours;
  char TL = char(difference->hours)+":"+char(difference->minutes)
```

I always end up getting an error here for (std::list::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it) specifically the ++ part and I can't figure out why. This part of the code is taken from a short tutorial on the internet but I don't fully yet grasp the idea of it that's where I'm struggling.

Comment: C++ uses block scoping. So `TimeSchedule` is local to the `if` and `else` blocks, and can't be accessed outside them.

Comment: Use `std::vector` as the substitute for Python lists.

Comment: Where do you declare `data`?

Comment: Similarly, `Finishes` and `Period` are local to their `if` blocks. You need to declare all your variables outside all the blocks.

Comment: You need to learn how variable scope works in C++, it's not like Python.

Comment: Never try to translate code from one language to another by going over it line by line. Different languages (can) work totally different  under the hood. Try to understand the algorithm/logic, learn C++ then convert. For C++ time functions have a look at : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: Is `getCurrentDOWAsString` supposed to be a function?

Answer (score 0):

Only focusing on the problem that you're asking about, a possible solution could be (assuming by reading the code snippet provided that we're inside another kind of loop):

```
std::vector<std::string> data = {};
    
if (getCurrentDOWAsString=="Saturday" || getCurrentDOWAsString=="Sunday")
    break;
else if (getCurrentDOWAsString=="Saturday")
    data = {"08:30","09:20","09:50","10:40","11:30"};
else
    data = {"08:30","09:20","10:10","11:00","11:30","12:20","13:10","14:00","14:45"};
    
for (auto& hour : data)
    cout << "Hour: " << hour << std::endl;
```

In summary:

- Use `std::vector` when you require a container that doesn't have a fixed size
- Use `std::string` almost always when you're working with strings. Try to not use `c-style` types in modern C``
- By using those collections, you enabled yourself to work with `ranged for loops`, and get rid out of the explicit usage of iterators to iterate over your collection in the way that you provide in your snippet